# How can I hide or show a custom margin on a visual studio editor window

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In a VSIX project, I can define a custom margin for an editor using the **Editor Margin** item template.

Is there any way that I can hide or show the custom margin from my Visual Studio extension?

Alternatively, is it possible for my extension to open a new editor window with a custom margin, which is not visible by default?

Comment: From experimenting with the [GiffDiffMargin project on GitHub](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin) it seems that if the margin contains a WPF UserControl, then setting Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed, or setting Width=0 will effectively hide the margin. (I still don't know if there is a way to actually add or remove a margin.)

Comment: Hi, if the margin can be catched by usercontrol,  you can try to set the `margin.visable =false` to hide the margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my application, I was able to handle it in the margin factory, which decides whether or not to create the margin.
If it does not create a margin, it simply return null.

In the margin factory, I import the TextDocumentFactoryService

```
[Import]
public ITextDocumentFactoryService TextDocumentFactoryService { get; set; }
```

and use it to get the filename in the editor

```
ITextDocument document;
var isok = TextDocumentFactoryService.TryGetTextDocument(wpfTextViewHost.TextView.TextDataModel.DocumentBuffer, out document ) ;
var fn   = document.FilePath ;
```

I have also defined an MEF service of my own, which is also imported into the margin factory. I use this service to

- determine whether the margin is required
- get the information I need to show in the margin

This is used to implement the annotation function in AnkhSVN2019. The relevant files are in [this directory](https://github.com/PhilJollans/AnkhSVN2019/tree/master/src/Ankh.UI/Annotate).